# Is there a way for Xamarin Studio to remember the keystore path and credentials?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Every time I do a Project->Publish Android Application, Xamarin Studio (v5.0.878) prompts for:

- Keystore Location
- Password
- Alias
- Key password

Is there a way to save this information so I don't have to enter it every time?

Comment: I think you should post this on http://xamarin.uservoice.com, this is pretty annoying to me, too.

Comment: Done. http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-product-suggestions/suggestions/6028434-save-keystore-path-and-export-location-when-doing

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your Android Project
2. From the Menu select Project -> Project Options
3. Under the Build section look for Android Package Signing

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't find it in the last xamarin 5.9, did you know where it is?

Comment: It is still there, same spot as described above. Make sure you open the actually android app project and no library or PCL project file ;)

Comment: I was trying with another subproject like you said, anyway I got a screen that says "IOS Bundle signing" that has another options, not same as you.